# Sphere in terms of manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, manifolds, spheres

Can we view a sphere as a two-dimensional manifold? Is this the reason why we call a sphere $S^2$?

Comment: Perhaps because $S^2$ is a 2-dimensional manifold.

Comment: Maybe because we regard it as a two-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It takes two "directions" to build.

Comment: I see that you changed the question completely, so now the answers don’t match anymore. Please change it back and ask your new question as a new question.

Comment: @EikeSchulte Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sphere $S^2$ is in a sense a  two dimensional subset of $\mathbb R^3$, as all so called 'surfaces' are (although this is not a very precise term). It is actually a two dimensional (differentiable) manifold, since it is around each one of its points the image of a (diffeomorphic*) map from an open region of $\mathbb R^2$ (two variables, and hence 'two dimensional') to $S^2$. For instance, if we pick $(0,0,-1)\in S^2$, it is in the (open) 'southern hemisphere' of $S^2$, which is the image of $\phi \colon D \subset \mathbb R^2 \to S^2\subset\mathbb R^3$,
$$\phi(x,y)=\left(x,y,-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right),$$
where $D$ is the unitary open disc $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\colon\, x^2+y^2<1\}$ (in particular $(0,0,-1)=\phi(0,0)$, and $(0,0)\in D$).

All this formalizes the intuitive notion that a 'piece' of the sphere $S^2$ (as happens with other 'surfaces') may be thought of as the result of deforming (not only continuously but also 'differentiably') a piece of plane, and hence it is two dimensional.

In the same fashion, the border of the disc $D$, that is the circumference $$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\colon\, x^2+y^2=1\},$$ can be considered as formed by 'arcs' which result from deforming segments of the real line; since a line has dimension one, the circumference (and any other 'nice' curve) is said to be one dimensional and that's why we use the notation $$S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,\colon\, x^2+y^2=1\}.$$

By analogy,
$$S^0=\{x\in\mathbb R\,\colon\, x^2=1\}=\{-1,1\}$$
or
$$S^3=\{(w,x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^4\,\colon\, w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}.$$
And in general, for $n\in \mathbb N$,
$$S^n=\{(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb R^{n+1}\,\colon\, x_0^2+x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1\}.$$

---

- A map is *diffeomorphic* if it's bijective, differentiable and it's inverse is also differentiable. The precise meaning of differentiability of $\phi^{-1}$ in cases like the one mentioned here is made precise in the study of differential geometry.

Comment: Bidimensional isn't a word in English (though there are a few google hits), it's just "two dimensional"

Comment: Well, some other Spanish speakers seem to have been taken into account by Google. =D
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Geometers call the surface of the usual sphere the 3-sphere, while topologists refer to it as the 2-sphere and denote it S^2

[image]

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere.html

Comment: That MathWorld article is wrong. "Geometers" use the same terminology as everyone else, i.e. $S^2$ is a two-dimensional surface. Yes, one book called $\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$ a "two dimensional sphere" once, but that's not a convention.

Comment: seconded @Dap comment. I have never heard the usual sphere embedded in $3$-space called a $3$-sphere and am shocked that a mathematician as recent as Coxeter used that terminology. It's possible the quotation is flat-out wrong, but regardless, you can rest assured that this terminology is  straight-up extinct.